# Шрифты подгружаются некорректно после перезапуска VisualStudio

Tags: html, css

Не кидайтесь только с санными тряпками на меня, я только начал и ничего не понимаю. Нашел я шрифт на google fonts, вставляю его как там написано, он работает, но когда я перезапускаю VS, шрифт отображается неправильно. Если открываю непосредственно страницу, не через VS, то все в порядке.
Если я в VS строки с шрифтами сотру и вставлю опять, то почему то все хорошо, но после перезапуска опять не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сохранил файл?
Вы пробовали скачать шрифт и загрузить не по ссылки, а по пути (к шрифту)?

Когда вы получили url шрифта.
Вставьте на первую строчку CSS файла вашего сайта!!!
На сайте подробно описано и показано, как правильно сделать. Там есть много разных ситуаций.

Как правильно загружать шрифты тут (не реклама): http://site4business.net/css/kak-podklyuchit-shrift.html#sposob2